# Trying to make a while loop work properly

Tags: java, eclipse, math, while-loop

I'm making a program that calculates the population for a year given the start year (2011) and increases the population by 1.2% every year. The population for 2011 is 7.000 (I'm using decimals, instead of billions). Here is the working part of my code

```
package src;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Demographics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input= new Scanner(System.in);

        //Part 1

        System.out.println("===--- Part 1 ---===");
        System.out.println("Population in 2011: 7.000");
        System.out.print("What is the desired year? ( > 2011) ");
        int startYear = 2011;
        int endYear = user_input.nextInt();
        while (endYear <= startYear){
            System.out.println("Invalid end year.");
            System.out.print("What is the desired year? ( > 2011) ");
            endYear = user_input.nextInt();
            break;
        }
        double t = 0.012; 
        double nbr = (endYear - startYear); 
        double pStart = 7.000; 
        double pEnd = pStart * Math.exp(nbr * t);
        DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
        System.out.println("Population in " + endYear + ":(nf.format(pEnd)));

    //Part 2

    System.out.println("===--- Part 2 ---===");
    System.out.print("What is the target population? ( > 7.000) ");
    double pTarget = user_input.nextDouble();
    while (pTarget <= pStart){
        System.out.println("Invalid target population.");
        System.out.print("What is the target population? ( > 7.000) ");
        pTarget = user_input.nextDouble();
        break;
    }
    while (pStart < pTarget){
        startYear++;
        pStart = pStart + (pStart * 0.012);
        System.out.println("Population in " + startYear + ": " + nf.format((pStart)));
    }
}
}
```

Part 1 of my code calculates the population of a year when the user enters it, then part 2 shows the calculations of how many years it will take when a user enters a population to get to that point.

Here is the code that doesn't work

```
//Part 3

    System.out.println("===--- Part 3 ---===");
    t = 1.2;
    pStart = 7.000;
    pEnd = pStart * Math.exp(nbr * t);
    while (pStart < pTarget){
        startYear++;
        pEnd = pStart + (pStart * 0.012);
        if (pEnd >= pStart * 2 ){
        System.out.println("Population in " + startYear + ": " + nf.format((pEnd)) + " Population growth rate " + ": " + (t / 2));
        }else{
            System.out.println("Population in " + startYear + ": " + nf.format((pEnd)) + " Population growth rate " + ": " + t);
        }
  }
```

Currently when i have part 3 in my code it does an infinite loop without multiplying the population. What I'm trying to do in part 3 is pretty much the same thing in part 2, but in part 3 it will display the population growth rate (t) and divide it by 2 every time the population doubles. For example:

Population in 2019 : 7.705 ; population growth rate : 1.2%

Population in 2020 : 7.798 ; population growth rate : 1.2%

Population in 2021 : 7.892 ; population growth rate : 1.2%

...

Population in 2068 : 13.873 ; population growth rate : 1.2%

Population in 2069 : 14.040 ; population growth rate : 0.6%

Anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Well, unless I am reading it wrong, you never change pStart within your loop.  So how will the loop exit condition ever be met?

Comment: What would i change about pStart in the loop?

Comment: Probably, nothing. Which most likely means your loop condition does not make sense.  Review your code line-by-line.

Comment: Should it be `while(pEnd < pTarget)`?

Comment: When i have while(pEnd < pTarget) it shows as 

Population in 2023: 2824.002 Population growth rate : 1.2

And ends the loop, not sure why

Comment: Ignoring the code (since you put so much and it looks messy), finding out when the population growth rate should double is simple math. `f(x)=7.000*1.012^x` models what your problem says where `x` is number of years after 2011. Do some rearranging to get `log(2)/log(1.012)=x`which results in 58; 2011+58=2069.1~. 

It also looks like you're not sure what `Math.exp` does. For what you're looking to do, you should probably use `Math.pow(1+t, nbr);`

Answer (score 3):

if you have problems in the loop the reason is in the condition!

```
while (pStart < pTarget){
```

so to end this code, inside the loop one of this situation has to happen:(according with your condition)

A)pStart should increase in value

B)pTarget should decrement in value

C)a "break;" have to occur

in your code you increase: startYear and pEnd, but this are not the condition to close the loop according with your condition. (i write it before:A,B,C)

1) also startYear are not re initialize it before the loop, and start already at a high value. you have to add bedore the loop:

```
startYear = 2011;
```

2) you should as far as possible to create new variables for the segment 3, is not to have problems like the one just described, is to be clear about what you are doing.

my advice for part three is this:
(Considering that I have no clear what I wanted to do reading your code, you have to cange it and make it good for you)

```
System.out.println("===--- Part 3 ---===");
        t = 1.2;
        startYear = 2011; // I add it
        double pEveryYear = 7000;
        while (pEveryYear < pTarget){
            startYear++;
            pEveryYear = pEveryYear + (pEveryYear * 0.012);
            if (pEveryYear >= pTarget  ){  // this condition cange only the print in the console
                System.out.println("Population in " + startYear + ": " + nf.format((pEveryYear)) + " Population growth rate " + ": " + (t / 2));
                break; // if you write it before the system.out you can't read it in the console.
            }else{
                System.out.println("Population in " + startYear + ": " + nf.format((pEveryYear)) + " Population growth rate " + ": " + t);

            }
      }
    }
```

this the console output for input like "8000":

```
===--- Part 3 ---===
Population in 2012: 7084.000 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2013: 7169.008 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2014: 7255.036 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2015: 7342.097 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2016: 7430.202 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2017: 7519.364 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2018: 7609.596 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2019: 7700.912 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2020: 7793.323 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2021: 7886.842 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2022: 7981.485 Population growth rate : 1.2
Population in 2023: 8077.262 Population growth rate : 0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two variables in the while loop that you try to compare however these do not actually get updated while iterating in the while loop. So after every iteration within the loop, the while condition just stays true.
See the last few lines below for a minor change to your **part 3 code** :

```
System.out.println("===--- Part 3 ---===");
t = 1.2;
pStart = 7.000;
pEnd = pStart * Math.exp(nbr * t);
while (pStart < pTarget){
    startYear++;
    pEnd = pStart + (pStart * 0.012);
    if (pEnd >= pStart * 2 ){
        System.out.println("Population in " + startYear + ": " + nf.format((pEnd)) + " Population growth rate " + ": " + (t / 2));
    } else {
            System.out.println("Population in " + startYear + ": " + nf.format((pEnd)) + " Population growth rate " + ": " + t);
    }
    pStart = startYear; // <-- NEW, you can probably use pStart instead of startYear in this code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only missing thing I see in your code is that you are not updating pStart every time you go through the loop. This will not only make your loop infinite but it's also doing a wrong calculation every time except the first iteration. I added only one line from your code:

```
System.out.println("===--- Part 3 ---===");
t = 1.2;
pStart = 7.000;
pEnd = pStart * Math.exp(nbr * t);
while (pStart < pTarget){
    startYear++;
    pEnd = pStart + (pStart * 0.012);
    if (pEnd >= pStart * 2 ){
        System.out.println("Population in " + startYear + ": " + nf.format((pEnd)) + " Population growth rate " + ": " + (t / 2));
    }else{
        System.out.println("Population in " + startYear + ": " + nf.format((pEnd)) + " Population growth rate " + ": " + t);
    }
    pStart = pEnd;
}
```